# Remove Duplicates and Remove unwanted String in array

Tags: ruby

I have an array that looks like this

```
@arr_sh = ['JAN 28, 2014','JAN 21, 2014', 'RATE THIS MOVIE', 'MOVIE INFO', 'WATCH IT NOW', 'JAN 14, 2014', 'RATE THIS MOVIE', 'MOVIE INFO', 'WATCH IT NOW', 'JAN 7, 2014', 'RATE THIS MOVIE', 'MOVIE INFO', 'WATCH IT NOW', 'DEC 31, 2013', 'DEC 24, 2013', 'DEC 17, 2013', 'RATE THIS MOVIE', 'MOVIE INFO', 'WATCH IT NOW']
```

As you can see there is repeating data 'RATE THIS MOVIE', 'MOVIE INFO', 'WATCH IT NOW'

i have tried `@arr_sh.uni`q and i still see duplicate values.

Question is 
1. How do i eliminate duplicates in this array
2. And then i want to create a separate array with the values of only dates from this array @arr_sh. so the new array should look like

```
@arr_date =  ['JAN 28, 2014','JAN 21, 2014', 'JAN 14, 2014', 'JAN 7, 2014', 'DEC 31, 2013', 'DEC 24, 2013', 'DEC 17, 2013']
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: `@arr_sh.uniq` will properly remove duplicates, but won't modify the array in place.  Use `@arr_sh.uniq!` to actually mutate the array stored in `@arr_sh`.

Comment: To retain just dates in the array. You can use @arr_sh.delete_if{|i| ["RATE THIS MOVIE", "MOVIE INFO", "WATCH IT NOW"].include?(i) }

Comment: @vidaica, you should qualify your suggestion, as you are assuming that `@arr_sh` never contains anything other than dates expressed as strings and the capitalized strings you wish to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

First off you need to use `.uniq!` if you want to mutate the array in place. You can use the Date class to parse your dates (mudasobwa's suggestion)

```
irb(main):007:0> @arr_sh.uniq.select {|v| Date.parse(v) rescue false}
=> ["JAN 28, 2014", "JAN 21, 2014", "JAN 14, 2014", "JAN 7, 2014", "DEC 31, 2013", "DEC 24, 2013", "DEC 17, 2013"]
irb(main):008:0> new_arr = @arr_sh.uniq.select {|v| Date.parse(v) rescue false}
=> ["JAN 28, 2014", "JAN 21, 2014", "JAN 14, 2014", "JAN 7, 2014", "DEC 31, 2013", "DEC 24, 2013", "DEC 17, 2013"]
```

Comment: Regular value is more appropriate for selecting. This one will be ok: `[A-Z]{3}\s[0-9]{1,2}\,\s[0-9]{4}`

Comment: That means you're depending on his dates to have only 3 letters for the month, and 4 numbers for the year. Mine just depends on his dates being the only thing with a comma. And why shouldn't they be if he's following the same style he shows above.

Comment: If you really want it to be better, this would work better. `\w+\s\d+,\s\d+`

Comment: Arrrgh. OP wants to select `Date` instances, right? `@arr_sh.uniq.select {|v| Date.parse(v) rescue false}` works here much better.

Comment: ah that's nice. I didn't know you could do that. When will that fail? Is it only if it's super ambiguous? @mudasobwa

Comment: @snowe2010 Am not sure I understood your question. “ambiguous”? Whether we want to get dates, `Date.parse` works; whether we wanna retrieve, say, `Array`s—`Array === v` does :-)

Comment: @snowe2010 you can make Date.parse trip on strange input, but most of the time it just makes a somewhat arbitrary decision on which order you followed for the fields. If you are sure that all your dates follow the same syntax, you can use strptime instead: `Date.strptime(v, '%b %e, %Y')`. It will raise an ArgumentError too (instead of taking a guess).

Comment: Hi Guys, None of the solutions worked. IS it because of the version of ruby i am working..I am on $ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [universal.x86_64-darwin13]

Comment: I see error messages that look like this

I think my i want to use Ruby 1.9.3... Why does the below error message have Framework version 1.8. What am i doing wrong here?

      private method `sub!' called for ["JAN 14, 2014", "RATE THIS MOVIE", "MOVIE INFO", "WATCH IT NOW"]:Array (NoMethodError)
      /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/date/format.rb:412:in `_strptime_i'

Comment: This should work just find for ruby 2.0. What is the exact code you are trying to call?

Answer (score 0):

To remove exactly duplicates (not values containing something specific) just use code:

```
@arr_sh.select{ |v| @arr_sh.select{|u| u == v }.size == 1 }
# => ["JAN 28, 2014", "JAN 21, 2014", "JAN 14, 2014", "JAN 7, 2014", "DEC 31, 2013", "DEC 24, 2013", "DEC 17, 2013"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This accomplishes what you'd like succinctly:

```
@arr_date = @arr_sh.uniq!.select{|str| str =~ /\A[A-Z]{3} \d{2}, \d{4}\z/ }
```

Which yields

```
p @arr_sh
#=> ["JAN 28, 2014", "JAN 21, 2014", "RATE THIS MOVIE", "MOVIE INFO", "WATCH IT NOW", "JAN 14, 2014", "JAN 7, 2014", "DEC 31, 2013", "DEC 24, 2013", "DEC 17, 2013"]

p @arr_date
#=> ["JAN 28, 2014", "JAN 21, 2014", "JAN 14, 2014", "DEC 31, 2013", "DEC 24, 2013", "DEC 17, 2013"]
```

Comment: I got the impression that that's @napsterdsilva's intent, but yes, that's important to keep in mind.

Comment: I meant you answer now is incorrect: `p @arr_sh` will not contain `"RATE THIS MOVIE"`-like crap.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: @snowe2010 has pointed out that my answer is very similar to his, which he posted earlier.  That is true and my apologies for not mentioning that, but in my defense, I somehow overlooked his answer.  I will leave mine up, however, as some of my remarks may be of some use to napsterdsilva, who is probably fairly new to Ruby.

I think you need to do something like this to extract the dates and nothing else:

```
require 'date'  

dates = @arr_sh.select do |str|  
  begin
    Date.strptime(str, '%b %d, %Y')
    true
  rescue ArgumentError
    false
  end
end
dates # => ["JAN 28, 2014", "JAN 21, 2014", "JAN 14, 2014", "JAN 7, 2014",
      #     "DEC 31, 2013", "DEC 24, 2013", "DEC 17, 2013"]
```

Unfortunately, Ruby does not have a method `is_a_date?(str, '%b %d, %Y')`. Instead, you just have to let [Date#strptime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) raise an exception when it chokes.  If `strptime` returns a date object, `true` is then executed and returned to `select`; else an `ArgumenError`is raised, which is caught by the rescue clause, and `false` is returned to `select`, then on to the next `str` object.

This will reject "My dog is named Diva", but it will also reject "JAN 99, 2014" and "FEB 29, 2014", which might slip by simpler filters.  It will also reject "Jan 28, 2014", something you may not want, but in that case you probably need to first ensure that all dates have a common format.

You're probably thinking this is an awful lot of trouble just to make sure a string is a date.  Yes, it's a pain, but I think something like this would be expected in a production environment, where the cost of a non-date evading your filter could be very high.

You might want to consider storing date objects rather than date strings.  That would allow you to easily manipulate and compare dates.  Your problem here would simplify to:

```
dates = @arr_sh.select { |e| e.class == Date }
```

Comment: That's literally almost exactly my answer, except using strptime.

Comment: @snowe, I apologize for not mentioning your answer.  I have rectified that.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be mean, I just thought I would point it out. And yes your answer is much more in depth than mine.